# Webpack: After applying "splitChunks" I've got a warning again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

This is my webpack.config.babel.js file:

```
// Import webpack module
import webpack from "webpack";
//Import path module
import path from "path";
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin";
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import fs from "fs";

const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

console.log("devMode: " + process.env.NODE_ENV);


/**
 * Code to get the values of environment variables during compilation time for the front-end
 */
//Get the root path. Our .env files and webpack.config.babel.js files are in the root path
const currentPath = path.join(__dirname);
const basePath = currentPath + "/.env";
// We're concatenating the environment name to our filename to specify the correct env file!
const envPath = basePath + "." + process.env.NODE_ENV;
// Check if the file exists, otherwise fall back to the production .env
const finalPath = fs.existsSync(envPath) ? envPath : basePath;
console.log("webpack.config.babel.js finalPath: " + finalPath);
// Set the path parameter in the dotenv config
const fileEnv = dotenv.config({ path: finalPath }).parsed;
// reduce it to a nice object, the same as before
const envKeys = Object.keys(fileEnv).reduce((prev, next) => {
  prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(fileEnv[next]);
  return prev;
}, {});



module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/client/index.js", //set entry file

    // Resolve to output directory and set file
    output: {
        path: path.resolve("dist/assets"),
        filename: "js/[name].bundle.js",
        chunkFilename: "js/[name].bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/assets"   //It's mandatory to define this publicPath to get access to the website when we reload pages
                                //or we access to them directly with url's which have directories of second level like 
                                //http://localhost:4000/directory-level-1/directory-level-2
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks : {
            chunks: "all",
            minSize: 30000,
            maxSize: 100000,
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./src/client/index.html",    //where is our template
            filename: "../index.html",              //where we are going to put our index.html inside the output directory
            minify: {
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeComments: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true
            }            
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "css/bundle.css",
            minify: {
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeComments: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true
            }             
        }),
        //With this entry we can get access to the environment variable for front-end
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys),
    ],
    //It help us to detect errors. 
    devtool: "source-map", 
    // Set dev-server configuration
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: './dist', 
        port: 3000,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },

    // Add babel-loader to transpile js and jsx files
    module: { 
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:[
                    { 
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                        query: {
                            presets: [
                                "@babel/preset-react"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                use: [
                    devMode ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 
                    "css-loader"],
                test: /\.css$/
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "style-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "saas-loader", 
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                loader: "url-loader",
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    publicPath: "/assets/images/",
                    outputPath: "./images/"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: "url-loader",
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    publicPath: "/assets/fonts/",   //It's mandatory to get access to the fonts when we reload pages or access directly
                    outputPath: "./fonts/"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

And the log that I've got when I create the code for the fron-end is:

```
basketmetrics3@1.0.0 compile /home/josecarlos/Workspace/nodejs/basketmetrics3
> NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config ./webpack.config.babel.js --progress

Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
devMode: production
webpack.config.babel.js finalPath: /home/josecarlos/Workspace/nodejs/basketmetrics3/.env
Hash: 89371cce2b9a1f4dc981                                                                                                                                                              
Version: webpack 4.38.0
Time: 18241ms
Built at: 2020-05-28 11:38:32
                                     Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                             ../index.html   4.29 KiB          [emitted]  
                         css/12.bundle.css   5.72 KiB      12  [emitted]  main~c4d3904e
                     css/12.bundle.css.map   7.89 KiB      12  [emitted]  main~c4d3904e
                         css/54.bundle.css    152 KiB      54  [emitted]  vendors~main~e41235fb
                     css/54.bundle.css.map    191 KiB      54  [emitted]  vendors~main~e41235fb
                         css/56.bundle.css   2.77 KiB      56  [emitted]  vendors~main~f9ca8911
                     css/56.bundle.css.map   3.56 KiB      56  [emitted]  vendors~main~f9ca8911
fonts/0a1ce4bd2f68c46725730d10762f050f.ttf   57.1 KiB          [emitted]  
fonts/575e4317521b381ac94c0c8207c81979.ttf    175 KiB          [emitted]  
fonts/580d0778ad254335be45bf58bb449f43.ttf    174 KiB          [emitted]  
fonts/a2c977bb9c9811e1b0e3eee168fbd913.ttf   56.3 KiB          [emitted]  
fonts/d08840599e05db7345652d3d417574a9.ttf    168 KiB          [emitted]  
fonts/dc466c6319df694a72360d9601596ef9.ttf   54.8 KiB          [emitted]  
                js/main~02be8cad.bundle.js   29.9 KiB       0  [emitted]  main~02be8cad
            js/main~02be8cad.bundle.js.map   52.7 KiB       0  [emitted]  main~02be8cad
                js/main~09bb5426.bundle.js   21.2 KiB       1  [emitted]  main~09bb5426
            js/main~09bb5426.bundle.js.map   49.8 KiB       1  [emitted]  main~09bb5426
                js/main~09eaa936.bundle.js   41.7 KiB       2  [emitted]  main~09eaa936
            js/main~09eaa936.bundle.js.map   65.1 KiB       2  [emitted]  main~09eaa936
                js/main~2202be32.bundle.js    134 KiB       3  [emitted]  main~2202be32
            js/main~2202be32.bundle.js.map    447 KiB       3  [emitted]  main~2202be32
                js/main~2faeff3f.bundle.js   51.4 KiB       4  [emitted]  main~2faeff3f
            js/main~2faeff3f.bundle.js.map    100 KiB       4  [emitted]  main~2faeff3f
                js/main~801e2957.bundle.js   43.9 KiB       5  [emitted]  main~801e2957
            js/main~801e2957.bundle.js.map   90.6 KiB       5  [emitted]  main~801e2957
                js/main~8d78bab2.bundle.js   51.9 KiB       6  [emitted]  main~8d78bab2
            js/main~8d78bab2.bundle.js.map   81.5 KiB       6  [emitted]  main~8d78bab2
                js/main~968a444c.bundle.js     49 KiB       7  [emitted]  main~968a444c
            js/main~968a444c.bundle.js.map    118 KiB       7  [emitted]  main~968a444c
                js/main~a5047cc6.bundle.js   35.5 KiB       8  [emitted]  main~a5047cc6
            js/main~a5047cc6.bundle.js.map   50.7 KiB       8  [emitted]  main~a5047cc6
                js/main~a85c8bbf.bundle.js   29.7 KiB       9  [emitted]  main~a85c8bbf
            js/main~a85c8bbf.bundle.js.map   56.6 KiB       9  [emitted]  main~a85c8bbf
                js/main~abdb67e0.bundle.js   48.4 KiB      10  [emitted]  main~abdb67e0
            js/main~abdb67e0.bundle.js.map   61.8 KiB      10  [emitted]  main~abdb67e0
                js/main~b5cb4aa8.bundle.js     29 KiB      11  [emitted]  main~b5cb4aa8
            js/main~b5cb4aa8.bundle.js.map   86.4 KiB      11  [emitted]  main~b5cb4aa8
                js/main~c4d3904e.bundle.js   32.5 KiB      12  [emitted]  main~c4d3904e
            js/main~c4d3904e.bundle.js.map   51.4 KiB      12  [emitted]  main~c4d3904e
                js/main~c66b9621.bundle.js     32 KiB      13  [emitted]  main~c66b9621
            js/main~c66b9621.bundle.js.map   58.6 KiB      13  [emitted]  main~c66b9621
                js/main~d3f54256.bundle.js   40.6 KiB      14  [emitted]  main~d3f54256
            js/main~d3f54256.bundle.js.map     98 KiB      14  [emitted]  main~d3f54256
                js/main~db67436b.bundle.js   45.2 KiB      15  [emitted]  main~db67436b
            js/main~db67436b.bundle.js.map   94.5 KiB      15  [emitted]  main~db67436b
                js/main~e2a1a646.bundle.js     30 KiB      16  [emitted]  main~e2a1a646
            js/main~e2a1a646.bundle.js.map   55.3 KiB      16  [emitted]  main~e2a1a646
                js/main~fc894998.bundle.js   33.1 KiB      17  [emitted]  main~fc894998
            js/main~fc894998.bundle.js.map   87.6 KiB      17  [emitted]  main~fc894998
        js/vendors~main~0436ed57.bundle.js   13.9 KiB      18  [emitted]  vendors~main~0436ed57
    js/vendors~main~0436ed57.bundle.js.map   72.5 KiB      18  [emitted]  vendors~main~0436ed57
        js/vendors~main~0928ebd2.bundle.js    103 KiB      19  [emitted]  vendors~main~0928ebd2
    js/vendors~main~0928ebd2.bundle.js.map    247 KiB      19  [emitted]  vendors~main~0928ebd2
        js/vendors~main~0cf2ab46.bundle.js   13.6 KiB      20  [emitted]  vendors~main~0cf2ab46
    js/vendors~main~0cf2ab46.bundle.js.map   68.4 KiB      20  [emitted]  vendors~main~0cf2ab46
        js/vendors~main~0d152872.bundle.js   37.4 KiB      21  [emitted]  vendors~main~0d152872
    js/vendors~main~0d152872.bundle.js.map    138 KiB      21  [emitted]  vendors~main~0d152872
        js/vendors~main~0f485567.bundle.js   23.9 KiB      22  [emitted]  vendors~main~0f485567
    js/vendors~main~0f485567.bundle.js.map    114 KiB      22  [emitted]  vendors~main~0f485567
        js/vendors~main~15d603ea.bundle.js   41.2 KiB      23  [emitted]  vendors~main~15d603ea
    js/vendors~main~15d603ea.bundle.js.map    152 KiB      23  [emitted]  vendors~main~15d603ea
        js/vendors~main~1c3a2c3f.bundle.js   22.4 KiB      24  [emitted]  vendors~main~1c3a2c3f
    js/vendors~main~1c3a2c3f.bundle.js.map    113 KiB      24  [emitted]  vendors~main~1c3a2c3f
        js/vendors~main~20e2ccca.bundle.js   17.3 KiB      25  [emitted]  vendors~main~20e2ccca
    js/vendors~main~20e2ccca.bundle.js.map   64.5 KiB      25  [emitted]  vendors~main~20e2ccca
        js/vendors~main~253ae210.bundle.js   14.2 KiB      26  [emitted]  vendors~main~253ae210
    js/vendors~main~253ae210.bundle.js.map   75.9 KiB      26  [emitted]  vendors~main~253ae210
        js/vendors~main~28014af5.bundle.js   23.4 KiB      27  [emitted]  vendors~main~28014af5
    js/vendors~main~28014af5.bundle.js.map    106 KiB      27  [emitted]  vendors~main~28014af5
        js/vendors~main~2fbb34c2.bundle.js   30.3 KiB      28  [emitted]  vendors~main~2fbb34c2
    js/vendors~main~2fbb34c2.bundle.js.map    132 KiB      28  [emitted]  vendors~main~2fbb34c2
        js/vendors~main~3a985ce4.bundle.js   28.5 KiB      29  [emitted]  vendors~main~3a985ce4
    js/vendors~main~3a985ce4.bundle.js.map   74.7 KiB      29  [emitted]  vendors~main~3a985ce4
        js/vendors~main~41983590.bundle.js   12.3 KiB      30  [emitted]  vendors~main~41983590
    js/vendors~main~41983590.bundle.js.map     57 KiB      30  [emitted]  vendors~main~41983590
        js/vendors~main~44621dc8.bundle.js   9.43 KiB      31  [emitted]  vendors~main~44621dc8
    js/vendors~main~44621dc8.bundle.js.map   45.2 KiB      31  [emitted]  vendors~main~44621dc8
        js/vendors~main~46e0dd6e.bundle.js   20.3 KiB      32  [emitted]  vendors~main~46e0dd6e
    js/vendors~main~46e0dd6e.bundle.js.map    101 KiB      32  [emitted]  vendors~main~46e0dd6e
        js/vendors~main~5244546d.bundle.js   31.6 KiB      33  [emitted]  vendors~main~5244546d
    js/vendors~main~5244546d.bundle.js.map    116 KiB      33  [emitted]  vendors~main~5244546d
        js/vendors~main~541cf30c.bundle.js   39.9 KiB      34  [emitted]  vendors~main~541cf30c
    js/vendors~main~541cf30c.bundle.js.map    139 KiB      34  [emitted]  vendors~main~541cf30c
        js/vendors~main~5737eb47.bundle.js   20.9 KiB      35  [emitted]  vendors~main~5737eb47
    js/vendors~main~5737eb47.bundle.js.map   92.8 KiB      35  [emitted]  vendors~main~5737eb47
        js/vendors~main~5c956a7a.bundle.js   25.9 KiB      36  [emitted]  vendors~main~5c956a7a
    js/vendors~main~5c956a7a.bundle.js.map    116 KiB      36  [emitted]  vendors~main~5c956a7a
        js/vendors~main~637b3a06.bundle.js   17.8 KiB      37  [emitted]  vendors~main~637b3a06
    js/vendors~main~637b3a06.bundle.js.map   89.6 KiB      37  [emitted]  vendors~main~637b3a06
        js/vendors~main~678f84af.bundle.js   32.4 KiB      38  [emitted]  vendors~main~678f84af
    js/vendors~main~678f84af.bundle.js.map    120 KiB      38  [emitted]  vendors~main~678f84af
        js/vendors~main~68d8c8c2.bundle.js   21.7 KiB      39  [emitted]  vendors~main~68d8c8c2
    js/vendors~main~68d8c8c2.bundle.js.map   78.7 KiB      39  [emitted]  vendors~main~68d8c8c2
        js/vendors~main~701f19e4.bundle.js   24.3 KiB      40  [emitted]  vendors~main~701f19e4
    js/vendors~main~701f19e4.bundle.js.map   89.2 KiB      40  [emitted]  vendors~main~701f19e4
        js/vendors~main~73914085.bundle.js   9.83 KiB      41  [emitted]  vendors~main~73914085
    js/vendors~main~73914085.bundle.js.map   47.8 KiB      41  [emitted]  vendors~main~73914085
        js/vendors~main~7a2ee6b6.bundle.js   14.7 KiB      42  [emitted]  vendors~main~7a2ee6b6
    js/vendors~main~7a2ee6b6.bundle.js.map     88 KiB      42  [emitted]  vendors~main~7a2ee6b6
        js/vendors~main~7d359b94.bundle.js   27.8 KiB      43  [emitted]  vendors~main~7d359b94
    js/vendors~main~7d359b94.bundle.js.map    116 KiB      43  [emitted]  vendors~main~7d359b94
        js/vendors~main~8ab0c962.bundle.js   34.9 KiB      44  [emitted]  vendors~main~8ab0c962
    js/vendors~main~8ab0c962.bundle.js.map    118 KiB      44  [emitted]  vendors~main~8ab0c962
        js/vendors~main~98431bb7.bundle.js   27.2 KiB      45  [emitted]  vendors~main~98431bb7
    js/vendors~main~98431bb7.bundle.js.map    114 KiB      45  [emitted]  vendors~main~98431bb7
        js/vendors~main~9acc357d.bundle.js   27.1 KiB      46  [emitted]  vendors~main~9acc357d
    js/vendors~main~9acc357d.bundle.js.map    119 KiB      46  [emitted]  vendors~main~9acc357d
        js/vendors~main~9c5b28f6.bundle.js   24.5 KiB      47  [emitted]  vendors~main~9c5b28f6
    js/vendors~main~9c5b28f6.bundle.js.map    132 KiB      47  [emitted]  vendors~main~9c5b28f6
        js/vendors~main~b5906859.bundle.js   40.2 KiB      48  [emitted]  vendors~main~b5906859
    js/vendors~main~b5906859.bundle.js.map     64 KiB      48  [emitted]  vendors~main~b5906859
        js/vendors~main~b790cc8c.bundle.js   27.3 KiB      49  [emitted]  vendors~main~b790cc8c
    js/vendors~main~b790cc8c.bundle.js.map    116 KiB      49  [emitted]  vendors~main~b790cc8c
        js/vendors~main~b8536e83.bundle.js   17.4 KiB      50  [emitted]  vendors~main~b8536e83
    js/vendors~main~b8536e83.bundle.js.map   58.7 KiB      50  [emitted]  vendors~main~b8536e83
        js/vendors~main~bed487d9.bundle.js   27.7 KiB      51  [emitted]  vendors~main~bed487d9
    js/vendors~main~bed487d9.bundle.js.map    108 KiB      51  [emitted]  vendors~main~bed487d9
        js/vendors~main~c16154f3.bundle.js   25.8 KiB      52  [emitted]  vendors~main~c16154f3
    js/vendors~main~c16154f3.bundle.js.map     98 KiB      52  [emitted]  vendors~main~c16154f3
        js/vendors~main~c37d664f.bundle.js   26.1 KiB      53  [emitted]  vendors~main~c37d664f
    js/vendors~main~c37d664f.bundle.js.map    104 KiB      53  [emitted]  vendors~main~c37d664f
        js/vendors~main~e41235fb.bundle.js  119 bytes      54  [emitted]  vendors~main~e41235fb
    js/vendors~main~e41235fb.bundle.js.map  111 bytes      54  [emitted]  vendors~main~e41235fb
        js/vendors~main~eea53fd7.bundle.js   32.3 KiB      55  [emitted]  vendors~main~eea53fd7
    js/vendors~main~eea53fd7.bundle.js.map    115 KiB      55  [emitted]  vendors~main~eea53fd7
        js/vendors~main~f9ca8911.bundle.js   12.8 KiB      56  [emitted]  vendors~main~f9ca8911
    js/vendors~main~f9ca8911.bundle.js.map   49.4 KiB      56  [emitted]  vendors~main~f9ca8911
        js/vendors~main~fc2f81ef.bundle.js   17.6 KiB      57  [emitted]  vendors~main~fc2f81ef
    js/vendors~main~fc2f81ef.bundle.js.map   76.7 KiB      57  [emitted]  vendors~main~fc2f81ef
Entrypoint main [big] = js/vendors~main~253ae210.bundle.js js/vendors~main~253ae210.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~0f485567.bundle.js js/vendors~main~0f485567.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~9acc357d.bundle.js js/vendors~main~9acc357d.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~28014af5.bundle.js js/vendors~main~28014af5.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~637b3a06.bundle.js js/vendors~main~637b3a06.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~0436ed57.bundle.js js/vendors~main~0436ed57.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~7a2ee6b6.bundle.js js/vendors~main~7a2ee6b6.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~46e0dd6e.bundle.js js/vendors~main~46e0dd6e.bundle.js.map css/54.bundle.css js/vendors~main~e41235fb.bundle.js css/54.bundle.css.map js/vendors~main~e41235fb.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~fc2f81ef.bundle.js js/vendors~main~fc2f81ef.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~41983590.bundle.js js/vendors~main~41983590.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~5c956a7a.bundle.js js/vendors~main~5c956a7a.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~2fbb34c2.bundle.js js/vendors~main~2fbb34c2.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~b5906859.bundle.js js/vendors~main~b5906859.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~5244546d.bundle.js js/vendors~main~5244546d.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~c16154f3.bundle.js js/vendors~main~c16154f3.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~c37d664f.bundle.js js/vendors~main~c37d664f.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~68d8c8c2.bundle.js js/vendors~main~68d8c8c2.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~5737eb47.bundle.js js/vendors~main~5737eb47.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~3a985ce4.bundle.js js/vendors~main~3a985ce4.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~0d152872.bundle.js js/vendors~main~0d152872.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~bed487d9.bundle.js js/vendors~main~bed487d9.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~b790cc8c.bundle.js js/vendors~main~b790cc8c.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~73914085.bundle.js js/vendors~main~73914085.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~7d359b94.bundle.js js/vendors~main~7d359b94.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~9c5b28f6.bundle.js js/vendors~main~9c5b28f6.bundle.js.map css/56.bundle.css js/vendors~main~f9ca8911.bundle.js css/56.bundle.css.map js/vendors~main~f9ca8911.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~678f84af.bundle.js js/vendors~main~678f84af.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~701f19e4.bundle.js js/vendors~main~701f19e4.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~eea53fd7.bundle.js js/vendors~main~eea53fd7.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~541cf30c.bundle.js js/vendors~main~541cf30c.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~0cf2ab46.bundle.js js/vendors~main~0cf2ab46.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~8ab0c962.bundle.js js/vendors~main~8ab0c962.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~b8536e83.bundle.js js/vendors~main~b8536e83.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~15d603ea.bundle.js js/vendors~main~15d603ea.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~20e2ccca.bundle.js js/vendors~main~20e2ccca.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~0928ebd2.bundle.js js/vendors~main~0928ebd2.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~98431bb7.bundle.js js/vendors~main~98431bb7.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~44621dc8.bundle.js js/vendors~main~44621dc8.bundle.js.map js/vendors~main~1c3a2c3f.bundle.js js/vendors~main~1c3a2c3f.bundle.js.map js/main~fc894998.bundle.js js/main~fc894998.bundle.js.map css/12.bundle.css js/main~c4d3904e.bundle.js css/12.bundle.css.map js/main~c4d3904e.bundle.js.map js/main~e2a1a646.bundle.js js/main~e2a1a646.bundle.js.map js/main~09bb5426.bundle.js js/main~09bb5426.bundle.js.map js/main~968a444c.bundle.js js/main~968a444c.bundle.js.map js/main~b5cb4aa8.bundle.js js/main~b5cb4aa8.bundle.js.map js/main~a5047cc6.bundle.js js/main~a5047cc6.bundle.js.map js/main~801e2957.bundle.js js/main~801e2957.bundle.js.map js/main~c66b9621.bundle.js js/main~c66b9621.bundle.js.map js/main~2faeff3f.bundle.js js/main~2faeff3f.bundle.js.map js/main~a85c8bbf.bundle.js js/main~a85c8bbf.bundle.js.map js/main~db67436b.bundle.js js/main~db67436b.bundle.js.map js/main~09eaa936.bundle.js js/main~09eaa936.bundle.js.map js/main~02be8cad.bundle.js js/main~02be8cad.bundle.js.map js/main~d3f54256.bundle.js js/main~d3f54256.bundle.js.map js/main~abdb67e0.bundle.js js/main~abdb67e0.bundle.js.map js/main~2202be32.bundle.js js/main~2202be32.bundle.js.map js/main~8d78bab2.bundle.js js/main~8d78bab2.bundle.js.map
 [11] ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/index.js + 9 modules 19.5 KiB {40} [built]
      |    10 modules
 [18] ./src/client/css/content.css 39 bytes {12} [built]
 [52] ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Dropdown.js + 2 modules 7.52 KiB {23} [built]
      |    3 modules
[117] ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/FormCheck.js + 2 modules 5.42 KiB {23} [built]
      |    3 modules
[131] ./node_modules/react-router-dom/esm/react-router-dom.js + 1 modules 31.2 KiB {31} [built]
      |    2 modules
[429] ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Modal.js + 3 modules 13.1 KiB {23} [built]
      |    4 modules
[431] ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Figure.js + 2 modules 1.61 KiB {23} [built]
      |    3 modules
[432] ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Navbar.js + 2 modules 5.88 KiB {25} [built]
      |    3 modules
[477] ./src/client/app.js 3.54 KiB {17} [built]
[479] ./src/client/css/header.css 39 bytes {12} [built]
[480] ./src/client/img/logo-basketmetrics-pink.png 11.3 KiB {12} [built]
[481] ./src/client/img/logo2.png 1.79 KiB {12} [built]
[843] ./src/client/css/footer.css 39 bytes {12} [built]
[845] ./src/client/index.css 39 bytes {12} [built]
[886] ./src/client/index.js 874 bytes {12} [built]
    + 947 hidden modules

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (1.91 MiB)
      js/vendors~main~253ae210.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~0f485567.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~9acc357d.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~28014af5.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~637b3a06.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~0436ed57.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~7a2ee6b6.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~46e0dd6e.bundle.js
      css/54.bundle.css
      js/vendors~main~e41235fb.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~fc2f81ef.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~41983590.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~5c956a7a.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~2fbb34c2.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~b5906859.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~5244546d.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~c16154f3.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~c37d664f.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~68d8c8c2.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~5737eb47.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~3a985ce4.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~0d152872.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~bed487d9.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~b790cc8c.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~73914085.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~7d359b94.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~9c5b28f6.bundle.js
      css/56.bundle.css
      js/vendors~main~f9ca8911.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~678f84af.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~701f19e4.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~eea53fd7.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~541cf30c.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~0cf2ab46.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~8ab0c962.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~b8536e83.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~15d603ea.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~20e2ccca.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~0928ebd2.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~98431bb7.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~44621dc8.bundle.js
      js/vendors~main~1c3a2c3f.bundle.js
      js/main~fc894998.bundle.js
      css/12.bundle.css
      js/main~c4d3904e.bundle.js
      js/main~e2a1a646.bundle.js
      js/main~09bb5426.bundle.js
      js/main~968a444c.bundle.js
      js/main~b5cb4aa8.bundle.js
      js/main~a5047cc6.bundle.js
      js/main~801e2957.bundle.js
      js/main~c66b9621.bundle.js
      js/main~2faeff3f.bundle.js
      js/main~a85c8bbf.bundle.js
      js/main~db67436b.bundle.js
      js/main~09eaa936.bundle.js
      js/main~02be8cad.bundle.js
      js/main~d3f54256.bundle.js
      js/main~abdb67e0.bundle.js
      js/main~2202be32.bundle.js
      js/main~8d78bab2.bundle.js


WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
Child html-webpack-plugin for "../index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = ../index.html
    [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/client/index.html 2 KiB {0} [built]
    [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
    [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
        + 1 hidden module
```

Everything is OK. In my laptop, I can access to the front-end and get data from the back-end. But, it seems that the size is "big" due to WARNING.

Is it possible that this warning appears by the sum of all the generated files? This means that when I access to the home, for example, all the files are loaded?

I guess that when I access to the home, only the files needed will be uploaded. If I'm not wrong, then, Should I disregard this WARNING?

Despite the size limits to the files that I have set up in my webpack.config.babel.js file, minimum 30K and maximum 100K, why I've got files like "js/main~2202be32.bundle.js" which a size bigger than 100K?

Or, am I doing something wrong? How can I improve my splitting to avoid this WARNING?

I'm working with webpack 4.38.0 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that this warning appears by the sum of all the generated files? This means that when I access to the home, for example, all the files are loaded?

Yes, the warning tells you that the **combined** size of all assets is too large:

> WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit

It even tells how to improve this:

> You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.

On a single page application you could [lazy load](https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/) some js parts.

Otherwise no matter how many chunks you create, any visitor has to download them at once when visiting your site.

> I guess that when I access to the home, only the files needed will be uploaded. If I'm not wrong, then, Should I disregard this WARNING?

No, the full entry point is loaded. If you only want to load parts of your js, then you have to split your js into multiple entrypoints. E.g. if you have multiple html files you can add an entry point per file. This way webpack can optimize your bundles.

Comment: Hi @anste!!! First of all, thanks for your appreciated help!!! About to create more entry points ... I've got a main menu with 5 options. Can I create an entry point for each one of them?

Comment: What are those options about? Does each of them point to a different html file, or are we talking about a single page application?

Comment: My application is a SPA so there is only one html file.

Comment: I think the best to me is lazy load. But, I've got a question ... Sorry, but I'm completly newbie with these issues. Imagine that I've got a component A. This component makes a call to other components (B, C and D). And these to others components. If I apply "lazy load" to component A, I guess that all the other components which are called for component A will not be loaded since component A would be loaded. Am I right?

Comment: That is correct if their chunk is not imported elsewhere.